# how to insert binded value of view in sqlite database in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I am a newbie in Ruby On Rails and i want to insert IP address and current time to database.  I have shown IP address and time on view,now i want to insert these values on sqlite

My view code:

```
<center><h1>EMS</h1>
<%= form_for(@emps) do |f| %>

 <%= hidden_field_tag :my_token, @token, :id => 'some_field_id' %>

  IP: <%= f.label require 'socket'
       ip=Socket.ip_address_list.detect{|intf| intf.ipv4_private?}
       ip.ip_address  %><br>


  Current Time:
    <%= f.label t = Time.now 
    t.strftime("%I:%M%p")  %>

  <%= f.submit  id: 'checkin', name:'action', value:'CheckIn'%>
```

OnController:

```
 def index
      @emps= Ems.new
      @emps.save
 end
```

i want to insert these ip and time in database sqlite

Comment: Those values will be automatically inserted on `form submission`.Please check in the db.If they are not present,then you might be getting `nil` values.In that case please share the `log` generated on `form submission` and your `controller code`.

Comment: Have a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html to build the form.

Comment: @pavan how can we check insert data into table in sqlite.. and i want to insert these value on button click

Comment: @Swetz What happens when the form is submitted? Did you any error.?

Comment: @Swetz You have to read this too http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

Comment: when i click on button then "uninitialized constant EmsController" error occured....

Comment: @Swetz Familiar error.Please read those guides before going further.Trust me it will help you.